# Prove $\frac {1}{(a-b)^{2}} + \frac {1}{(b-c)^{2}} + \frac {1}{(c-a)^{2}}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $a,b,c$ are distinct real numbers such that $a^{2}*(1-b+c)+b^{2}*(1-c-a)+c^{2}*(1-a+b)=ab+bc+ca$

First, I tried to expand the bottom of what we need to prove.

$\frac{1}{a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}}+\frac{1}{b^{2}-2bc+c^{2}}+\frac{1}{c^{2}-2ac+a^{2}}$

I then tried to expand what we are given.

$a^{2}-a^{2}*b+a^{2}*c+b^{2}-b^{2}*c-b^{2}*a+c^{2}-c^{2}*a+c^{2}*b=ab+bc+ca$

$a^{2}-a^{2}*b+a^{2}*c+b^{2}-b^{2}*c-b^{2}*a+c^{2}-c^{2}*a+c^{2}*b-ab-bc-ca=0$

Add 1 to both sides

$a^{2}-a^{2}*b+a^{2}*c+b^{2}-b^{2}*c-b^{2}*a+c^{2}-c^{2}*a+c^{2}*b-ab-bc-ca+1=1$

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: 2 identical questions on the same day?